# Edición de Temas Android

Tags: java, android, material-design

Hoy estoy teniendo una situación particular con una App de Android que estoy desarrollando. Soy muy nuevo trabajando para Android. Uso Android Studio.

El tema es el siguiente. Estoy tratando de darle un poco de la personalidad de la empresa a la aplicación, por lo cual, mediante el **Theme Editor**, cree un nuevo tema que hereda de `AppCompat.Ligth.NoActionBar` (Que es el tema que venía utilizando por defecto) y le modifiqué algunos colores. Sin embargo, no logro modificar el ***Color de Fondo de los Botones***, ni el `Highligth Color` , ni colores de otros componentes como el `Switch`, etc...

¿Dónde encuentro éstas configuraciones?

Necesito que todo quede Anaranjado, y por el momento éstos controles tienen una variedad de Celestes...

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Si no mal recuerdo todos los controles se rigen por el colorAccent del style, si quieres colores individuales para cada control debes de crear un style para cada uno.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te ayude, pero los colores los puedes ver en `app/res/values/colors.xml`
particularmente en el proyecto que yo estoy trabajando ahora, tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#ff6600</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#e65100</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#ff8c1a</color>
<color name="colornav">#d8ff6d00</color>
<color name="ColorParaBoton">#ffa64d</color></resources>
```

Puedes crear valores para color a tu gusto, y asignarlos a los botones como este de ejemplo:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/TuBonton"
         android:background="@color/ColorParaBoton"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="35dp"
         android:text="@string/RegistrarUsuario" />
```

Espero y te ayude.

Comment: Pero ahí tendría q editar tooooodos mis botones 1 a 1 ?

Comment: Y otros controles ? como el switch ?